# Disallow author with robots.txt

Tags: seo, google, robots.txt

I would like to **disallow the authors** (of posts for example) in the file robots.txt. In fact, I noticed that for some of my sites, Google indexed the authors of articles, which I don't want to. Someone thinks is it possible ?

(I tried something like Disallow: **/author/** but I'm not sure it works...)

Thank you in advance,

ArbreMojo.

Comment: Do you use Yoast SEO?

Comment: Yes I do ! :) Is there a way to do that with Yoast SEO ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Yoast SEO, you can go to Users > All Users, and in the Yoast SEO settings, check *Do not allow search engines to show this author's archives in search results*. See this [link](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/how-do-i-noindex-urls/#author).

OR

With robots.txt, you can add:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /author/*
```

OR

You can also add the robots meta-tag to the appropriate pages:

```
function custom_function_filter_wp_robots( $robots ) {
    if(is_author()) {
        $robots['noindex'] = true;
    } 

    return $robots;
}

add_filter( 'wp_robots', 'custom_function_filter_wp_robots' );
```